# Visual inheritance for RadGridViews event handling possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, gridview, telerik

I have 2 projects:

- Project A which consists of a Usercontrol named BaseUC which consists of a RadPanel and a RadGridView (both have modifier set to public)
- Project B which consists of a Usercontrol which inherits from BaseUC
  (from the class itself). Project A is included as referenced dll in Project B

Now the situation is so:

- Both elements from BaseUC are shown in the DerivedUC.
- The RadLabel I can edit without problems (properties) in project B
- The GridView has its properties grayed out in project B
- If I give GridView events which I implement as virtual in project A and overwrite them in project B I run into the problem that I get an exception as soon as I try to fire the events. Same if I try to manually add events to the gridview in project B.

So my question is twofold there but comes down to the basic question if event handling is possible for visually inheritted RadGridViews:

1. How can I get the RadGridView to have its properties editable in design view in project B?
2. How can I handle events there?

That is if these two things are possible at all.

Comment: The control events on the UserControl would largely be intended to be consumed *by* the UserControl.  The form is only going to see/have access to the events you define and fire in the UserControl.    Not enough details to know for sure, but the US may not have access to the B.A events either. Examples are the NumericUpDown or ComboBox, those are compound controls but the NUD consumes their events and fires new ones related to the NUD (UC in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the child controls contained in your UserControl as a public property, that is creating a public property that returns the child control and not just making the child variable public. This will make the child control available to sink event handlers and set public properties. Note that this breaks one of object orientation rules namely, encapsulation....but rules are meant to be broken for certain cases that fits the requirement :)